# Prevent two event types from being fired

Tags: jquery, event-handling, keycode

I am in a situation where I want to toggle something when the user either clicks or types `enter`.

Unfortunately, I'm working on a massive site which, somewhere, listens for the `enter` key and triggers `.click()` on **some** items when they receive an `enter` keyup. I can't find where, and I would not want to (or be able) to change it if I could find it, but it behaves just like this:

```
$("#item").on("keyup", function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){$('#item').click();}
});
```

The result is that my "toggle" script runs twice when a user types `enter`, undoing itself.

```
$('body').on('click keyup', '#item', function(e) {
    console.log("-----------------");
    if(e.type=="click") {
        console.log("Event Type: " + e.type);
        //toggle something
    } else {
        console.log("Event Type: " + e.type+ ", keyCode: " + e.keyCode);
        //toggle something
    }
});
```

([Here's a JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/dFMrF/))

Is there a way to prevent both `keyup` and `click` from being fired when someone hits enter? The obvious answer is to remove the `keyup` part of the script, however, this won't work for me because the [enter] --> [click] script is not applied universally, so I need the `enter` key to work on the elements where it does not apply.

Comment: You can remove the previous binding(s) using `.off()`

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I do not want to change the existing binding, but I guess I was wrong when I said I would be "unable" to change it. I'm just "unable" in the sense that it's needed as is.

Comment: Ah okay, I thought you couldn't change their code, but I guess you don't want to change that behavior.

Comment: Upon further investigation, I found that it isn't Javascript causing the `enter` to trigger `click`. It's the default browser behavior for `<a>` elements. If you hit `enter` on a link, it registers as a `click`. So basically, I need to make my function work on both links and non-links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use event namespacing.

IE:

```
$(el).on('keyup:hamza', function(){ 
    //Detect if it was called by an element with event namespaced and do different code
})
```

You could also use off('keyup:hamza') to remove only your events..